# Creating Navision service using Navision application server?

Tags: service, navision

I am trying to create a service. I am using nassql.exe, this is what I have done
[image]

But It's not  added into the list of services, like

[image]

I am new to Navision, what I need to do for creating it as a service like above two by default  services. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missing a parameter `installasservice`.

```
nassql.exe appservername=TheNasName, servername=TheServerName, database=TheDatabaseName, company="The Company", nettype=tcp, startupparameter=SomeStartupParameter, installasservice
```

Without this parameter you launching NAS from comandline. For example to debug it.

There is also `uninstallasservice` parameter to remove previously installed service.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
nassql.exe appservername=JB-xx23NAV-SQL, servername=JB-xx23NAV,database="Demo Database NAV (6-0)", company="CRONUS India Ltd.", nettype=tcp,startupparameter=”JOBQUEUE”, objectcache=40000, installasservice
```

- appservername - is the name of service that has been installed by NAS
  Installer.
- Servername    - is the name of SQL Server where database
  Resides.
- database - is the database name on the SQL Server.
- Company       - is the company name in the database where you want to
  run NAS.
- Startupparmerter - is the parameter for Startup (you can
  search for NAS in Codeunit 1, Function NASHandler).

Comment: you just copied and pasted the command, attribute ''nettype'' is appearing twice. please edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks, delete one NetType